# neo4j, cypher relationship exist, relation property exsit with where, order by and limit

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j db with this pattern (:User)-[:ANSWER_TO_QUESTION]->(:Question).

In my app there is some question and some user nodes. A user will answer to question and the answer will save on a relationship between user and question.

User can skip the question and the answer will save null on relationship to question.

Every question has a answer cycle time for re asking the question if user answered to question and a no answer cycle time for re asking question if user didn't answer to question.

Now i want to query for questions that a special user didn't asked, or didn't answered and the no answer cycle period passed or answered and the answer cycle period passed. Order them by priority of question and then return one question.

I tried query with union but I can't return limit 1 on total result. So query will return 3 question, one from each union query.

```
MATCH (n:Users {user_name:$user_name}),(q:Questions)
Where NOT (n)-[:ANSWERED_OF_QUESTION]->(q)
return q as question
ORDER BY question.priority DESC 
LIMIT 1
UNION MATCH (n:Users {user_name:$user_name})-[r:ANSWERED_OF_QUESTION]->(q:Questions)
Where r.answer is null and r.created+q.no_answer_cycle < $now_time
RETURN q as question
ORDER BY question.priority DESC 
LIMIT 1
UNION MATCH (n:Users {user_name:$user_name})-[r:ANSWERED_OF_QUESTION]->(q:Questions
Where r.answer is not null and r.created+q.answer_cycle < $now_time
RETURN q as question
ORDER BY question.priority DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

I tried with OPTIONAL MATCH, and CASE but didn't get to my result. Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get my answer with this:

```
call apoc.cypher.run("MATCH (n:Users {user_name:$user_name}),(q:Questions)
Where NOT (n)-[:ANSWERED_OF_QUESTION]->(q)
return q as question
ORDER BY question.priority DESC
LIMIT 1 UNION MATCH (n:Users {user_name:$user_name})-[r:ANSWERED_OF_QUESTION]->(q:Questions)
Where r.answer is null 
RETURN q as question
ORDER BY question.priority DESC
LIMIT 1
UNION MATCH (n:Users {user_name:$user_name})-[r:ANSWERED_OF_QUESTION]->(q:Questions)
Where r.answer is not null 
RETURN q as question
ORDER BY question.priority DESC
LIMIT 1",{user_name:"saeed@saeed.com"})
yield value
RETURN value
ORDER BY value.question.priority
DESC LIMIT 1'
```

EDIT:
Second solution: Inspire from [lokesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1465110/lokesh)

```
MATCH (q:Questions), (n:Users {user_name:$user_name})
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r:ANSWERED_OF_QUESTION]->(q)
WHERE (r.answer is null )
OR  (r.answer is not null )
RETURN q as question
ORDER BY question.priority DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Any suggestion for improvement?

Answer (score 1):

How about simplifying it in this way ?

```
MATCH (q:Questions)
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((:Users {user_name:$user_name})-[:ANSWERED_OF_QUESTION]->(q))
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Users {user_name:$user_name})-[r:ANSWERED_OF_QUESTION]->(q)
WHERE (r.answer is null and r.created+q.no_answer_cycle < $now_time)
  OR  (r.answer is not null and r.created+q.answer_cycle < $now_time)
RETURN q as question
ORDER BY question.priority DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Type mismatch: expected Relationship but was List<Relationship> (line 2, column 24 (offset: 107))
"WHERE NOT EXISTS ((n)-[r]->(q))"

Comment: Ahh yes, that variable length pattern returns a list, which we would need to unwind it first, please check the edits and try again.

Comment: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'H': expected 'i/I' (line 4, column 2 (offset: 110))
"WHERE NOT EXISTS ((n)-[r]->(q))"

Comment: I think we can't use where after unwind

Comment: Yes, that strategy was wrong. I discarded my prev answer and edited with another approach, see if it works.

Comment: It work but in wrong way. Results contains only questions with no relation to user.

Comment: There are two where clauses, first match statement also has a where clause. That should filter out wrong results.